# us states plot in R with election results

Tags: r, ggplot2, usmap

I have plotted a figure of the US states in R.

Here is the very simple code:

```
library(usmap) 
library(ggplot2)
plot_usmap(region = 'states')
```

And here is the resulting figure:
[Figure of US states in R - states are not colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8dUd.jpg)

Furthermore, I have a csv file containing the names of the states in US, and a color value, equal to red if that state voted for Republicans or blue if the state voted for Democrats. This is the top 5 rows of the CSV file:

| State | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Alabama | #E81B23 |
| Alaska | #E81B23 |
| Arizona | #1405bd |
| Arkansas | #E81B23 |

How can I fill the states of my figure based on the colors in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color the regions specified in the `plot_usmap()` function, you can provide your data via `data=` and then set the `values=` argument to the column in your data used for mapping the colors.

Here's an example with some randomly-generated data.  The `plot_usmap()` is using a dataset that includes the 50 US states + the District of Columbia, so you'll want to make sure they are all in your dataset or you may get some NA labels.

```
library(usmap) 
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

color_data <- data.frame(
  state = c(state.name, "District of Columbia"),
  the_colors = sample(c("A", "B"), size=51, replace=TRUE)
)

plot_usmap(
    region = "states",
    data = color_data,
    values = "the_colors",
    color="white"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E81B23", "#1405bd"))
```

[image]

Note that I think the lines between the states look good in white, so `color="white"` fixes that.  You may also notice that you typically don't specify the actual color in the dataframe - you can specify that via `scale_fill_manual(values=...)`.  In your case, you can use `scale_fill_identity()`.

For your data, just make sure the `"States"` column in your dataset is renamed `"state"` and it should work.